# How to perform HTTP-Request during pre-processing in Jmeter?

Tags: http, jmeter, preprocessor

Before the actual test execution, I want to call some HTTP APIs and parse the response out of it before handling it to my SSH Command sampler. What's the best way to do it in Jmeter? Like there is a pre-processor for JDBC request, then why not a pre-processor for HTTP request?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why not just executing http before?why you don't want it to be a sampler?

Comment: I don't want to do that as a sampler because then it shows up as another test. I just want to perform some http calls before the actual test so that only main test is visible

Comment: What do you mean by not visible? Not include in listeners? Dashboard Report? Not effect timer?  not waiting for response...?

Comment: Yes, let's say a listener like 'View Results Table'

Comment: You can put listener inside simple controller with ssh sampler to record only it

Comment: That's not an option for me bcz I have to put a global View Results Tree to capture many other executions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) you can use to make an arbitrary HTTP Request using underlying [Apache HttpComponent](https://hc.apache.org/) libraries.

1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of your SSH Command sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

   def httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
   def httpGet = new HttpGet("http://example.com")
   def httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)
   def responseData = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())

   log.info('----- Response -----')
   log.info(responseData)
   vars.put('response', responseData)
   ```
3. The above code executes simple [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request to http://example.com website, prints the response to *jmeter.log* and additionally stores it into `${response}` JMeter Variable which you can reuse later on where required.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Execute HTTP Request]

References:

- [HttpClient Quick Start](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: This looks good, I can try that but don't you agree that similar to JDBC pre-processor, Jmeter should have a capability of pre-processing with HTTP requests? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the HTTP calls before the SSH Command Sampler in the ThreadGroup. Pre-processors are mostly used to perform some modifications on the request before executing the sampler.

Comment: I don't want to do that because then it shows up as another test. I just want to perform some http calls before the actual test so that only main test is visible

Comment: Well, i'd rather get the results just in case the test is slow and you don't know why. It can come from the http requests themselves. Using JTL files, you can only process the results you are interested in.

Comment: Makes sense, I'd process the results